# How to get width 100% right in overlay with CSS

Tags: css, width, overlay, margin

I am creating an overlay but the width ends up wrong on the right. Where do I go wrong? In the end I want some buttons that are 100% width of the screen, minus some margin.

```css
body
{
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0px;
}

.a1 
{
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); 
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.a2 {
  width: 100%;
  border: 5px solid blue;
   }
```

```html
  <div class="a1">
    <div class="a2">The width is going to far on the right</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Remove `width:100%;` on your `.a2` class.

Comment: add `box-sizing: border-box;` to your `.a2` - your width is 100% + 10px border without it.  Read this to understand: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: @Pete, thanks so far that seems to work

Comment: @Pete, only when I use margin, it still becomes buggy. It seems that I need to use padding in the parent container, instead of margin on the current item

Comment: margin is not calculated with box-sizing - if you want to use margin, you will need to use it with `calc` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to specify `width: 100%` on the child div `a2`.  As a block element, it will automatically fill the available width of the parent element, which is set at `100%`.

Your `a2` CSS becomes:

```
.a2 {
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
```

In this way your margins are respected and work as expected:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body
{
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0px;
}

.a1 
{
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); 
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.a2 {
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="a1">
  <div class="a2">The width is going to far on the right</div>
</div>
```

**Following OP comment about sizing of elements**

I notice that you don't specifically mention that you are using `border-box` as your `box-sizing` methods.  I have added this into the snippet now.

Using `border-box` means that when you specify the size of a box, you are including the borders inside that size.

For example, if the width is set to 100%, this is 100% *including* any borders you have on your elements.  Most normalized stylesheets set `box-sizing` to `border-box` by default.

Comment: Ah... so making the body 100% and its margin 0 it will work. Yet... now when I want to add padding to body or the overlay, again 100% gives me the 100% from the browser, not from the container it is in. How do I deal with this?

Comment: @MichielKrol I've added an edit to clarify the box-sizing using `border-box` which will also assist you with your layout troubles

Comment: Thank you, it is indeed the border-box that I needed to use, and the right way to use padding on the parent container instead of margin on the current item